# Convert Nested JSON to csv using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, export-to-csv

I am converting nested json to csv, but i am getting empty file created. below is the sample json file

```
    {
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": [
          "ga:socialNetwork"
        ],
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:pageviews",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "dimensions": [
              "(not set)"
            ],
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "433"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "totals": [
          {
            "values": [
              "433"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rowCount": 1,
        "minimums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "433"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "maximums": [
          {
            "values": [
              "433"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "isDataGolden": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the powershell i am using, not sure what I need to modify to get the jason values. I am using get-content to get the contents fo the file and converting from json to powershell object and then converting back to csv form the results set.

```
((Get-Content -Path "Z:\Informatica\IICS\ProjectFolders\Dev\Government\Google_Analytics\Files\GA_PageViews_City_2023-07-05.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json ).results | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content Z:\Informatica\IICS\ProjectFolders\Dev\Government\Google_Analytics\Files\GA_PageViews_City_2023-07-05.csv
```

Comment: First, you're specifying `.results` which isn't a property, so that is passing nothing down the pipe. Beyond that, this JSON is structured nothing like a CSV. What is your desired output?

Comment: besides the issue mentioned above, you can convert your `ConvertTo-Csv ... | Set-Content ...` to just `| Export-Csv ...` instead.